# Как убрать границу у поля ввода при фокусе?

Tags: css, bootstrap, input, focus

Как убрать бордер у `input:focus`. Используется Bootstrap. Стили вида `input:focus { border: none; }` не работают.

Comment: `input:focus {outline: none;}` попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border) — не единственный способ задать обводку элемента. В вашем случае обводка задаётся с помощью [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/outline). Отключите его.

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' autofocus />
```